# Callback URL in oauthConsumer Component of cakephp

Tags: oauth, cakephp-2.0

I am integrating Yammer in my application and I am using OAuthConsumer Component of cakephp.

After yammer authorization it is not redirecting me to the callback url.

The token generated by get_request_token function is an array having key and secret. After generating token it is redirecting me to Authorize page of Yammer but once i click Authorize button, it is displaying the code there. I am passing the callback url (`http://localhost.com/test/yammer/callback`) in the get_request_token also.